# Tags that are set via Azure cloudshell do not appear in the portal

Tags: azure-cloud-shell

When trying to set tags via Azure cloudshell I ran in to an issue that these tags are not changed in the portal. checking the settings via PowerShell everything seems to have worked properly.

What I did:

```
PS Azure:\> $r = Get-AzResource -ResourceName automateMe-ResourceGroupName automation
PS Azure:\> $r.Tags.Add("Status", "Approved")
PS Azure:\> Set-AzResource -Tag $r.Tags -ResourceId $r.ResourceId -Force
PS Azure:\> $r.tags

Key     Value
---     -----
Status  Approved
```

Attached you can see a screenshot from the portal. Also 15 min later these have not changed:

[no tags in the portalview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cepJh.png)

When editing the tags in the portal they are visible as expected. But I can still add the same tag via the portal which are then also visible. Checking the tags again after creation via portal the output is the same as above.

When creating another tag via portal only this one does not appear in cloudshell!?

So I guess there is something wrong with syncing from cloudshell to the portal. 
Any hints?

when creating it via portal it seems to be synced some minutes later.

**after another 30 minutes it works in every direction now.**

Thx
Christian

Comment: when creating it via portal it seems to be synced some minutes later.

Comment: I suggest to track any progress by editing the question instead of posting tgem as comments. It will help you to get an answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

it seems to have fixed itself. After waiting another 15 to 30 mins they finally appear